# Remove Euro Value and money format with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I already know how to get a value from a label, the problem is that its showing something like

`€123,453.28`

I need to remove the eurosign and the commas to be able to make a calculation.

Not remove the decimal point of course

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#TxtVatExcluded").keypress(function () {
                var invoicedAmmount = $("#MainContent_VehicleInformationControl_LblInvoicePriceValue").text();
                alert(invoicedAmmount);
                if (invoicedAmmount > 0) {
                    var ammountWithoutVat = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val();
                    var result = (ammountWithoutVat / invoicedAmmount) * 100;
                    $("#OutputLabel").html(result + " %");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: What was the value, and what do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"€123,453.28".replace(/[^\d.]/g,"") // Replace every non digit char or dot char
                                    // With an empty string.
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ds9fx/)

So in your code:

```
var ammountWithoutVat = $("#TxtVatExcluded").val().replace(/[^\d.]/g,"");
var result = (pareseFloat(ammountWithoutVat, 10) / invoicedAmmount) * 100;
```

Comment: I have almost the same problam with ammoutWithoutVat, its an asp.net textbox with a mask like this:  <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server"
TargetControlID="TxtVatExcluded" 
Mask="9,999,999.99"
MessageValidatorTip="true" 
MaskType="Number" 
InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
DisplayMoney="Left"  CultureName="nl-BE"
/>

Comment: if I type a value like 123,00, its returning me ..123

Comment: @LuisEValencia. What is the question\answer\comment?

Comment: pls see the edited question, I changed the code and also uploaded an image.

Comment: when I type something in the textbox, the alert shows me what I show in the screenshot, I need it to be just numbers so I can make the calculation.

Comment: I shouldnt remove the dots, dot is decimal separator, comma is hundreds or thousands separator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11327/discussion-between-gdoron-and-luisevalencia)